# R Shiny progress bar for R Mardown HTML rendering

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, progress-bar, knitr

I have an R Shiny app which prompts the user to input a dataset and click a download button to generate an R Markdown report based on that dataset. The bulk of the data transformations are made on the .rmd file, all that the shiny server is doing really is collecting inputs as parameters for RMarkdown and and rendering it as html.

Is it possible to implement any kind of progress bar? I've tried to incorporate withProgress() but there's nothing that increments in my server code to feed on to it. Ideally I'd be able to print the RStudio console messages with the chunks being knitted, but I'm really just after anything that will give some feedback to the user as some reports take very long to process.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withProgress` in the `downloadHandler`, and include some `incProgress` in the **Rmd** file:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name", "Name", value = "Johan Rosa"),
  downloadButton("render", "Render report")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$render <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      withProgress(
        message = 'Calculation in progress',
        detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
          rmarkdown::render(
            input = "input.Rmd",
            output_file = file
          )
        }
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

***input.Rmd:***

````
---
title: "render with progress"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "2024-02-28"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shiny)
```

```{r}
incProgress(1/3)
Sys.sleep(2)
```

```{r}
incProgress(1/3)
Sys.sleep(2)
```

```{r}
incProgress(1/3)
Sys.sleep(2)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `{waiter}` package can help with your task. Check the [documentation](https://waiter.john-coene.com/#/)

I'm using here the `onBusy` feature, you can show a Spinner to the user while rendering the file.

Note: You have to create  input.Rmd in your working directory for this example to work.

```r
library(shiny)
library(waiter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useWaiter(),
  waiterOnBusy(html = spin_loaders(42)),
  textInput("name", "Name", value = "Johan Rosa"),
  downloadButton("render", "Render report")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Waiter$new(id = )
  output$render <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      rmarkdown::render(
        input = "input.Rmd",
        output_format = html_document(),
        output_file = file
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```